# How to create user authentication in sql server 2008 using electron.js

Tags: sql-server, powershell, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

sql connection can be done if we have correct user name, password & DB name. I want to create a user if pre defined user is not available. is there a way to do it perhaps during the installation process (installing the .exe) ? **Maybe using a powsershell script**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use thhis batch script https://gist.github.com/djangofan/3792028 with some changes.